# Angular nested routing

Tags: angular, load, router, lazy-evaluation

I have this project :

Main routes :

```
 const routes: Route[] = [
     {
         path: 'login',
         loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule'
     },
     {
         path: 'dashboard',
         loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
         // canActivate: [AccessGuard]
     },
     {
         path: '',
         loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule'
     },
     {
         path: '**',
         loadChildren: 'errors/404/404-error.module#Error404Module'
     }, ];
```

Dashboard module :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AppNavbarModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: ''
            }
        ])
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

AppNavbarModule

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppNavbarComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [
        AppNavbarComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AccessGuard
    ]
})
export class AppNavbarModule { }
```

Dashboard.html

```
<app-navbar #navbarComponent></app-navbar>
```

Navbar component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})

-- implementation is useless
```

I'm only displaying an empty blank page when loading to localhost:4200/dashboard
when it should display the content on my navbar html file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the route to render an empty page, not a particular component. 
You should swap this part:

```
RouterModule.forChild([{
   path: '',
   redirectTo: ''
}])
```

For this:

```
RouterModule.forChild([{
   path: '',
   component: AppNavbarComponent
}])
```